# When using Firebase Authentication service, how to use the same email address to log in to different apps in the same project?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm developing two apps using Firebase Authentication service and i got a question about the firebase documentation:

This new account is stored as part of your Firebase project, and can be used to identify a user across every app in your project, regardless of how the user signs in.

I registered User A in an app, Can User A be allowed to log in on other apps in my project?Through my experiments, I can't prove that User A can't log in on other apps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All applications in a single project share the same backend resources. That means that they also share the same set of users. So if a user signs in to one app in the project, they are also registered (though not automatically signed in) for other apps in that project.

If you don't want that, you should put the apps in separate projects.